Syntax Error on using the class variables on C#
I have syntax error which I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm used to VB, but I don't know exactly the equivalent code on C#.
The [script_id] won't be recognized that it is pattern from PostViewModel. I don't know if it's allowed to have IF statement within those braces.
     //A class inside the Models Folder
     public class PostViewModel
     {
          public string script_id { get; set; }
          public string script_code { get; set; }              
          public string status { get; set; }
     }
     
     //A class inside Models Folder
     public class ScriptConstants
     {
       public const string script_id = "script_id";
       public const string script_code = "script_code";           
       public const string status = "status";
    }

     //Part of the Home controller accessing an oracle database and will read the    row 
     while (reader.Read())
     {
          var Scripts = new PostViewModel
          { 
              If (ColumnExists(reader, ScriptConstants.script_id) == true)
              { 
                 script_id = reader(ScriptConstants.script_id)
              }
          };  
      }


    private bool ColumnExists(IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName,   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
              return true;
            }
       }
       return false;
    }

I'm used to WITH statement on VB but I know there's no equivalent code in C#. Maybe someone could correct my code on how to solve this. Also the constant class file is inside the Models folder, is that a right thing to do?

You can't have that kind of condition inside an initializer. You can however use the  condition ? true : false format

What is the error, and where in the code?

The inner code in the while loop needs to read like this:
var Scripts = new PostViewModel();
if (ColumnExists(reader, ScriptConstants.script_id))
{ 
   Scripts.script_id = reader(ScriptConstants.script_id);
}


You're very close:
var Scripts = new PostViewModel();
if(ColumnExists(reader, ScriptConstants.script_id))
{
    Scripts.script_id = reader[ScriptConstants.script_id].ToString();
}

The syntax for C# uses the square bracket accessor.  Also, it returns a value of type Object, so you need to ToString for strings, or cast for other object types.
The == true comparison is implicit in your conditional check, and not required.
Also, you need a semi colon at the end of the assignment line, and do not need it after the close brace of your conditional statement.
I would also recommend you add an else branch and assign a default if for some reason your column doesn't exist.
